# Gnuplot: Load String From File

Tags: gnuplot

I have many charts, each generated by individual Gnuplot (5.0) files and individual data files. They all share common display characteristics such as background, font, etc. Occasionally, there is a call to change the look of all the charts--for example, change the background color of all charts from "#000000" to "#333333".

To continue with the example, what I would like do is place the color value into a textfile called "backgroundColor.txt" and then pull that value into each file as it's plotted. Even better would be to have background color preference on the first line, font on the second, etc.

Example textfile.txt:

```
"#000000"
"Arial,10"
```

Gnuplot psuedo-code:

```
backgroundColor_var = file[1]
font_var = file[2]

set terminal pngcairo enhanced background backgroundColor_var font font_var size 600,200
```

Then I need make only one change, rather than many, many changes.  Thanks in advance,

Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you simply put the whole variable declaration in the config file?

File `textfile.txt`:

```
backgroundColor_var = "#FFFFFF"
font_var = "Arial,10"
```

And then use it with

```
load 'textfile.txt'
set terminal ...
```

This solution works on any OS and you can put everything inside, line style definitions, terminal settings, fonts and so on

Comment: I looked at 'Load' and dismissed it for some reason.  Probably because I thought it had to be more complicated than this.  Thanks Christoph, this is a great solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `system` command. In linux, the following should work:

```
config = "config.cfg"
backgroundColor_var = system( sprintf("sed -n '1p' %s", config) )
font_var = system( sprintf("sed -n '2p' %s", config) )
```

The `sed -n 'Np'` command selects the Nth line of the config file. 
In windows, you would need to install gnuwin32 to use this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  Your suggestion is _VERY_ close.  When I print the variable value, I get the value I'm looking for: `"#FFFFFF"`; however, when I add the variable to the `set terminal` command, I get the following error: `unrecognized color name and not a string "#AARRGGBB" or "0xAARRGGBB"`.

Comment: I figured it out (the error was mine.)  I mistakenly put double quotes around the value inside the parameter file--effectively giving me `""#FFFFFF""` where it mattered.  Once I removed those, it worked perfectly.  Thanks vagoberto for the perfect solution.

Comment: Well, it is not perfect :) Christoph's answer is easier. My answer would be suitable for more complicated tasks (for example, read the header of a datafile)

Comment: I was when I commented!  :)  But I agree, I had to give the answer to Christoph.  Thanks for responding nonetheless.  I will keep that one in my back pocket for when I need it.  Cheers.